# Application version updated but older version executed due to offline files

Tags: delphi, networking, version, offline

When i install a new version of my Delphi 7.0 application on the network and i restart the application on the client desktop it sometimes executes the previous version, but the modified date is the new one...

After some googleing i found out that Windows Offline Files sometimes causes this, and therefore i added the folowing PE Flags to my .dpr

```
const
  IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_TERMINAL_SERVER_AWARE = $8000;
  // Following are already defined in D7's Windows.pas
  IMAGE_FILE_REMOVABLE_RUN_FROM_SWAP       = $0400;
  IMAGE_FILE_NET_RUN_FROM_SWAP             = $0800;

{$SetPEOptFlags IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_TERMINAL_SERVER_AWARE}

{$SetPEFlags IMAGE_FILE_REMOVABLE_RUN_FROM_SWAP 
  or IMAGE_FILE_NET_RUN_FROM_SWAP}
```

Even though i added these flags i (sometimes - it is not really reproducable) still have the same issues.

Can someone explain what these PE flags do and how to prevent windows to "cache" my exefile when running from a network path.

Comment: sync center -> manage offline files -> view your offline files. If you don't have the executable there, you're on the wrong track.

Answer (score 0):

**The PE Flags**

When a process is created, the executable files are mapped into memory. These executable files are held in virtual memory pages like other virtual memory such as stack or heap memory.

The virtual memory manager may decide to unload pages from physical memory if the memory is needed elsewhere. And that could happen to your executable's pages.

Another scenario is that the executable file was never in physical memory at all. The process starts and mapped pages are loaded on demand. If some parts of the executable file are not touched then they will not get fetched from disk.

If the file resides on removable media, or on network volumes this can cause problems. Running process may be unable to access their own executable's memory. This results in runtime failure.

These PE flags force the executable to be copied to the swap file and mapped from there. The copy happens during the process creation and is potentially expensive.

These PE flags won't help you at all. If you start the process and the network is not available, all you have to work with is the offline copy. Include these PE flags and you'll just get the loader to copy the offline copy to the swap file. With the same end result.

**Preventing the executable file from being cached**

Before you can get an answer to that you would need to get a clean diagnosis of what causes the behaviour you observe. As it stands you suspect offline files, but I see no evidence for that being the cause. Perhaps something else is behind this. Perhaps your file server is mis-configured. Really, there could be all sorts of explanations for this.

Instead of adding PE flags to your executable, you really need to step back and accurately diagnose the problem. Once you know what the problem is then you will be in a position to attempt to solve it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will be more specific: the file resides on the network. Desktop 1 is running the file (say version 1); Desktop 2 is running version 1 too. I update the version to v2. I ask desktop1 and 2 to close the executable and restart it . Desktop 1 now runs v2, but desktop 2 somehow runs v1. Even after a reboot it STILL runs v1. When i copy the v2 from the network location to a different subfolder and then rerun it from desktop 2 it finally runs v2

Comment: I don't think you need to be more specific. The question was very clear already. You asked what the PE flags mean. Did you mean to ask a different question?

Comment: well the last bit of my question was: "how to prevent windows from "cacheing" my exefile when running from a network path"

Comment: Step 1: diagnose the problem. I suppose that I should have anticipated that this question would go this way. You asked about PE flags but in reality you don't seem to care about them. It's frustrating when the wrong question is asked.